# Restarting animations ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation

The animation stops working after i

1. Transits to another view controller and comes back
2. app goes to background and then comes back to foreground

i am using this code (in viewwillappear)to achieve blinking animation

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.4, options:[ UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut , .repeat], animations: {

        self.logoLabel1.alpha = 0.0
        self.logoLabel2.alpha = 0.0

    }, completion: nil)
```

Can anyone help me?
thanks.

Comment: Try viewDidApper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, it is the expected behaviour. Animations will stop when the view disappears, either by minimizing the app or by showing another viewcontroller. Move your animation code to viewDidAppear, and the animation will not stop when you move to any other viewcontroller and come back. For handling the case where animation stops when app goes to background, use following code:

Inside your viewDidAppear,

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(willEnterForeground), name: .UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
```

and in your viewWillDisappear,

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
```

and write this function inside your viewcontroller,

```
@objc func willEnterForeground() {
    // your animations
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.4, options:[ UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut , .repeat], animations: {

        self.logoLabel1.alpha = 0.0
        self.logoLabel2.alpha = 0.0

    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: It is not working :( 
there must be an underlying problem i suppose?

Comment: I installed Spring Pod for the animations and now everything is working as it should.
I dont know why observer is not working with UIView.animate method.
Thanks for your answer.